# How to validate Select2 Plugin array using jQuery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-select2

I am trying to validate this form. I want to make sure the user selects at least 1 user and enters something in the body. The form uses a select2 field and a `summernote` textarea. What am I doing wrong?

The Form:

```
    <form id="ShareThisForm" method="post">
        <div class="modal fade" id="Share" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                        <h5 class="modal-title text-light"><i class="fas fa-share-alt mr-1"></i>Share to</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body p-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <span class="input-group-text">
                                        <i class="fas fa-user mr-2"></i>Users
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <select class="form-control select2bs4 select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" data-placeholder="Share to" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="sharing" name="users[]" data-select2-id="sharing">
                                    <?php foreach($this->Database->get('users')->fetchAll() as $user){ ?>
                                        <option value="<?=$user['id']?>"><?=ucwords(str_replace('_',' ',str_replace('.',' ',$user['username'])))?></option>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control wysihtml5-alt" name="body"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" name="ShareThis" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-share-alt mr-1"></i>Share</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The Script:

```
    <script>
        var select2label
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ShareThisForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    "users[]": {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    body: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                },
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using `select2` plugin for your `users` multiple selection `dropdown`. `jQuery validate` will **not** work with `select2` plugin by **default** you need to use [errorPlacement](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) method to add a required `field` message label below the select field.

I can see you are using `boostrap` as well for your modal so you can also a class `text-danger` to make sure the `validation` message is in **red** color.

If **nothing** is `selected` from the `dropdown` then the `validation` message will appear on clicking `submit` button OR if something is `selected` then we need to use `select2` plugin `change` function to make sure our error label is removed is after selecting a user. We need to store the `select2` label as a global variable so that it can be accessible to removed after a selection is made **OR** else show the error message again.

```
$('#users').on("change", function(e) {
    if (select2label){
        select2label.remove(); //remove label
    }
});
```

As you are adding your `select` option name attributes as an `array` => `users[]` you need to add the rules for validation like this below:

```
"users[]": {
   required : true
},
```

**Edit:** As you have mentioned now that you are using summernote for your textarea and you have provided a reference to ignore it. I have added `ignore: ".note-editor *",` in my answer as well.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
//Initiate select2 plugin on users
$('#users').select2()

//global var for select 2 label
var select2label

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ShareThisForm").validate({
    ignore: ".note-editor *", //ignore summernote validation
    rules: {
      "users[]": {
        required: true
      },
      body: {
        required: true,
      },
    },
    errorPlacement: function(label, element) {
      if (element.hasClass('select2bs4')) {
        label.insertAfter(element.parent()).addClass('mt-2 text-danger');
        select2label = label
      } else {
        label.insertAfter(element).addClass('mt-2 text-danger');
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      //submit modal form
    },
  });
});

//watch the change on select - if label exist then remove it
$('#users').on("change", function(e) {
  if (select2label) {
    select2label.remove(); //remove label
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Share">
 Open Modal
</button>

<form id="ShareThisForm" method="post">
  <div class="modal fade" id="Share" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
          <h5 class="modal-title text-light"><i class="fas fa-share-alt mr-1"></i>Share To</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="'.$this->Language->_ARRAY['Close'].'">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body p-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">
                          <i class="fas fa-user mr-2"></i>Users
                        </span>
              </div>
              <select class="form-control select2bs4" multiple data-placeholder="Share to" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="users" name="users[]" data-select2-id="users">
                <option value="0">User1</option>
                <option value="1">User2</option>
              </select>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control wysihtml5-alt" name="body"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" name="ShareThis" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-share-alt mr-1"></i>Submit</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: works like a charm for the select2 field, but not exactly for the wysihtml5 textarea.

Comment: @L.Ouellet it’s working for both in my answer ! Please check again. Run snippet.

Comment: The thing is, you only partially fix the issue, because yes the users field now works, the body field no longer works. So I can't accept it. Also your snippet does not include the wysihtml5 (summernote).

Comment: The summernote creates additionnal stuff that messes up jQuery's validation. We must ignore the note-editor class and all that follows by adding ```ignore: ".note-editor *",``` Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086841/jquery-validate-with-summernote-editor-error-cannot-read-property-replace-of

Comment: @L.Ouellet dont you think its unfair that you did not even mentioned all these things in your question and i still provided a solution based on what i could see like `select2` plugin. I spent time a good time writing up this very good solution for you and you are asking something which is was not mentioned in the question ????

Comment: Just add the parameter to complete your solution and I will mark it as answered ;) It's not unfair, unfair would of been to edit your answer and take credit for it. I just want to make sure that someone who encounters the same situation has the proper and complete solution

Comment: @L.Ouellet Are you able to provide a minimal example of summer note in your question ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221694/discussion-between-always-helping-and-l-ouellet).